# Problem to initialize a object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got a weird error when I try to create a Screen object. Before It worked without any problem, but I got this error when I added a new attribute to the User class. This attribute is related to Screen in a relation many to many through user_screens. This is the error:

"InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to compile. Exception was probably suppressed within a hasattr() call. Message was: One or more mappers failed to compile. Exception was probably suppressed within a hasattr() call. Message was: Class 'zeppelinlib.screen.ScreenTest.Screen' is not mapped"

These are the classes:

```
class Screen(rdb.Model):
    """Set up screens table in the database"""
    rdb.metadata(metadata)
    rdb.tablename("screens")

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column("title", String(100))
    ip = Column("ip", String(20))
        ...

user_screens = Table(
            "user_screens",
            metadata,
            Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id")),
            Column("screen_id", Integer, ForeignKey("screens.id"))
        )

class User(rdb.Model):
    """Set up users table in the database"""
    rdb.metadata(metadata)
    rdb.tablename("users")

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("name", String(50))
    ...

    group = relationship("UserGroup", uselist=False)
    channels = relationship("Channel", secondary=user_channels, order_by="Channel.titleView", backref="users")
    mediaGroups = relationship("MediaGroup", secondary=user_media_groups, order_by="MediaGroup.title", backref="users")
    screens = relationship("Screen", secondary=user_screens, backref="users")
```

I might not added new relation to user because I really don't know what the problem is...

Thanks in avance!

Comment: What is rdb.Model? Is it the result of a declarative_base() call?

Comment: rdb.Model is a library built on SQLAlchemy. That library is related to GROk, the CMS what I'm using. The problem might come up because of that library, I'm not sure, but it's weird anyway!

Comment: I believe your problem is related to the CMS library you are using. The example that you give is very close to the SQLAlchemy ORM many-to-many tutorial which works fine for me. I tried your code on my machine swapping out the GROK for SQLAlchemy's declarative and it worked fine.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the primary join via the `primaryjoin` keyword argument on one (don't know which one) of your `relationship`s. Sometimes (in complex relationship graphs) SQLAlchemy has a hard time to figure out how it should go about. Worked for me more than once, albeit on 0.5.x.